# Is there a (significant) difference in storing a "small" Entity and a "big" Entity

Tags: google-app-engine

When I said "small" entity, I mean `Entity` for example having just 1-2 fields, when I said "big" entity, those that have many fields and/or have `EmbeddedEntity` on it having many fields.

So my question would be, is there a difference in Storing (put) and retrieving (get):

- Both in put time and get time
- In cost per `put` and `get`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put/get time are related to how long it takes to serialize your entity, as well as how long it takes to transmit your entity over the network.  This will generally depend more on the size of your entity in bytes, rather than the number of fields.  An entity with 1 900KB field will take longer to process than an entity with 100 4-byte fields.

Cost for puts/gets are described in the GAE pricing page.  The get costs don't depend on entity size.  The put costs depend on the number of indexes being updated - not the total number of fields or total size.  Unindexed fields don't affect the cost, so you could have a huge entity with many unindexed fields and one indexed field - it'll cost the same to put as an entity with a single 4-byte indexed field.

Note also that only indexes that require updating affect your cost.  If you update an entity with many indexed fields, but the fields haven't changed and the index doesn't require an update, you don't get charged for those.

Don't forget about storage costs for large entities though.